# re-sizing ggplot geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble creating a figure with `ggplot2`. I am using `geom_dotplot` with center stacking to display my data which are discrete values for 4 categories.

For aesthetic reasons I want to customize the positions of the dots so that

1. reduce the empty space between dots along the y axis, (ie the dots are 1 value large)
2. The distributions fit and don't overlap

I've adjusted the `bin` and `dotsize` to achieve aesthetic goal 1, but that requires me to fiddle with the ylim() parameter to make sure that the groups fit in the plot. This results in a plot with more whitw space and few numbers on the y axis.

Question: Can anyone explain a way to resize the empty space on this plot?

My code is below:.

```
plot <- ggplot(figdata, aes(y=Counts, x=category, col=strain)) + 
            geom_dotplot(aes(fill=strain), dotsize=1, binwidth=.7, 
                         binaxis= "y",stackdir ="centerwhole", stackratio=.7) +
            ylim(18,59)

plot + scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + 
       geom_errorbar(stat="hline", yintercept="mean", 
                     aes( ymax=..y..,ymin=..y.., group = category, width = 0.5), 
                     color="black")
```

Which produces:

[image]

EDIT: Incorporating jitter will allow the all the data to fit, but I don't want to add noise to this data and would prefer to show it as discreet data.
adjusting the binwidth and dotsize to 0.3 as suggested below also fits all the data, however it leaves too much white space.

[image]

I think that I might have to transform my data so that the values are steps smaller than 1, in order to get everything to fit horizontally and dot sizes to big large enough to reduce white space.

Comment: im not sure if i understand... is it that due to the density of the dots, when your data is plot, the dots from the groups overlap, with some getting cut off  (looks like t the rhs)? So you then increased the y-limits so the plot would be smaller to allow all the dots to be plot

Comment: If I do not reset the ylim(), the 4 groups overlap much more. Changing the dimensions doesn't help, the dots are too large because of the dotsize and binwidth parameters. In order to reduce the space between the layers of dots. I want to know if there's a way to reduce the overall size and adjust the dimensions with everything fitting.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Have a look at using the `width` and `height` parameters to your output device to make the plot wider, and so allow the points to fit. You are already using the `dotsize` and `binwidth` parameters- how about adding some  `jitter` to the plot to reduce the  vertical distance between points. An example below - does it help any?

Comment: `set.seed(1) ; figdata <- data.frame(category=letters[1:2],
 strain=paste0(letters[1:2], c(1:2, 2:1)),  Counts=rnorm(1e3)) ;
pdf("test.pdf", height=5, width=10); 
ggplot(figdata, aes(y=Counts, x=category, fill=strain)) +
 geom_dotplot(dotsize=0.3,  binwidth=.3,
 binaxis= "y",
 stackdir ="centerwhole", 
 position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.height=0.9)) ; 
dev.off();`

Comment: @user20650 are the width and height parameters in the ggplot2 layer?

Comment: thanks, link fixed. I did come to a solution for my image, but it was sort of a work-around R, so I don't know if I should post it as an answer.  I was able to manipulate the dots distributions in Adobe Illustrator after saving the R plot as a metafile. After opening the file in ai, ungrouping and releasing the clipping mask, the individual components can be adjusted. Plus the text remains sharp without pixel-ation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is using `coord_cartesian`:

```
plot + scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + 
  geom_errorbar(stat="hline", yintercept="mean", 
                aes( ymax=..y..,ymin=..y.., group = category, width = 0.5), 
                color="black") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(17,40))
```

Which gives me this plot (with fake data that are not as neatly distributed as yours): 
[image]